# Simple print utility

Tags: linux, printing, printer

Is there a Linux program that is run with `print /dev/usb1 file.ps` that simply tells a USB printer to print a Postscript file?

I don't need spoolers or daemons or support for extra features like double sided pages. I also don't care about communicating information back to the computer like ink level or completion time.

Does a utility like this exist? If not, do all Postscript-capable printers have a fairly standard protocol for receiving Postscript and printing it? I could possibly write a program to do this. :)

Comment: 1) try `cat file.ps > /dev/usb1`. 2) It would be easier to install a CUPS than to write a protocol.

Comment: @Archemar 1) Does writing the .ps file to /dev/usb1 actually work? I don't have a printer now to test. 2) I wouldn't write a protocol but would write the code implement the specific printer model's protocol in order to dump Postscript directly. It might help other people since the total time wasted installing CUPS could be replaced by the time I spend writing this utility.